# Excel gives a "wrong formula" error when there OBVIOUSLY isnt one. I copied the formula straight from Microsoft's website

Tags: excel, formula, conditional-formatting

I want to shade alternating rows, so I searched for a formula and found one on Microsoft's site. It's this:

```
=MOD(ROW(),2)=0
```

And I've seen it being used in many other tutorials for the same thing too, but my Excel says there's something wrong with it. What is the problem?

Comment: Which version of Excel? Are you accidently entering another "=" in the front?

Comment: 2015. Here is a screenshot of the error, i didnt mess up the formula.
[link](http://i.imgur.com/DgFYNNg.png)

Comment: In that context, *remove* the "=". The "=" at the beginning is only used when *editing cells* as this instructs Excel that the content is a formula. In other dialogs that take formulas there is no need to specify that it is a formula.

Comment: Thanks, that solved it. Very weird that they would mess up like that. Im new to excel so i didnt know.
[here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Apply-shading-to-alternate-rows-in-a-worksheet-a443b0f5-2025-42f6-9099-5de09c05e880) is a link to where they say it should be used, and [here](https://support.content.office.net/en-us/media/f5c1aae4-2792-42c9-b611-9b30de46a56a.jpg) is a link to the image they use in their tutorial which tuns out is straight up wrong.

Comment: Please check that removing the leading `=` didn't just change the formula to be `="MOD(ROW(),2)=0"`.  It does in Excel 2010.  What version (e.g. English, German, etc) of Excel are you using? Some foreign versions (i.e. foreign for me, i.e. non-English versions) require a `;` instead of a `,` to separate parameters in formulae.

Comment: You were right, it changes the formula to ="MOD(ROW(),2)=0". Using ; instead of , removes the quotes, but it still doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

If semicolons work for you, you may also need to adapt the function names (mod, row) to their localized versions.